# firebase_storage and integration_test make error

Tags: flutter, integration-testing, firebase-storage

when I install `firebase_storage: ^7.0.0` there is an error appears which is:

```
Because firebase_storage_web 0.1.1+3 depends on crypto ^2.1.5 and no versions of firebase_storage_web match >0.1.1+3 <0.2.0, firebase_storage_web ^0.1.1+3 requires crypto ^2.1.5.
And because every version of integration_test from sdk depends on crypto 3.0.0, integration_test from sdk is incompatible with firebase_storage_web ^0.1.1+3.
And because firebase_storage 7.0.0 depends on firebase_storage_web ^0.1.1+3 and no versions of firebase_storage match >7.0.0 <8.0.0, integration_test from sdk is incompatible with firebase_storage ^7.0.0.
So, because elderly_app depends on both firebase_storage ^7.0.0 and integration_test any from sdk, version solving failed.
pub get failed (1; So, because elderly_app depends on both firebase_storage ^7.0.0 and integration_test any from sdk, version solving failed.)
```

I also have:

```
dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
  integration_test:
    sdk: flutter
```

when I delete on of these (`firebase_storage` OR `integration_test`) it works and the error disappear,

what can I do to avoid this error without deleting one of them?

Comment: Have you got any workaround for this?

Comment: @SoumikBhattacharjee no